# Spark memory requirements for querying 20gb

Tags: csv, apache-spark, memory

Before dive into the actual coding I am trying to understand the logistics around Spark.
I have server logs split in 10 csv's round 2GB each.
I am looking for a way to extract some data e.g. how many failures occured in a period of 30 minutes per server.
(the logs have entries from multiple servers aka there is no any predefined order in time and per server)

Is that something I could do with spark?
If yes would that mean I need a box with 20+ GB of RAM? 
When I operate in Spark with RDDs,does take into account the full dataset?E.g. an operation of ordering by timestamp and server id would execute to the full 20GB dataset?

Thanks!

Comment: I didn't get exactly what is the problem. Are you loading the data and getting errors during the load? And then you want to understand how those operations work after this?

Comment: I have watched many videos and tutorials but I am still not getting any answer to the very basic stuff thus my question here. Let me rephrase: what are the hardware requirements to load ,order by time stamp and group by an ID using Spark for 20GB of txt files. Thanks for your time,Alex

Comment: That is hard to say, it depends how you are developing you code. Because with spark I can process 50 Gb of data in my local machine. The point we need to check you code. If you can share what you did until now could be better to understand what are you doing.